# Language where negation is the default

Tags: english, morphology

I was wondering how in English we say "I can" and "I can not" 
the negative is the longer one, in terms of morphemes, but is there any language where the negative is the default and the positive is the longer construct?

Comment: The closest that occurs to me is something like in English "That smells" implying "That smells bad", whereas for example in German "That tastes" implies "That tastes good".

Answer (score 6):

This happens in some Dravidian languages. Specifically, in these languages, positive verbs have a tense marker and a person marker; negative verbs differ from them only in lacking the tense marker.

A set of examples from Old Kannada (from [Miestamo 2010](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/~matmies/publications/miestamo-negwithoutneg-web.pdf)):

> no:ḍ-uv-eṃ see-FUT-1SG ‘I will see’
>
> no:ḍ-id-eṃ see-PST-1SG ‘I saw’
>
> no:ḍ-eṃ see-1SG ‘I do / did / will not see’

As you can see, the negative is formed simply by omitting the tense marker (with the result that it's ambiguous for tense); there's no explicit marker of negation.

Comment: Is there no explicit negative marker in the language at all?

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't know enough about Dravidian languages to answer that, but I assume there are negators for other functions than simple verb negation, at least.

Comment: A similar case is Swahili where at least some tenses (like the present) include a tense marking prefix in the positive which is not found in the negative. Also, since some some such markers cannot carry stress, a dummy prefix is inserted to carry the stress if necessary; this is also not found in the negative. An example: _ni-na-ku-la_ (1sg-PRES-STRESS-eat = I eat) vs _si-l-i_ (1sg.NEG-eat-NEG). Granted, the negation is marked – twice in fact, in a negative pronoun and a negative suffix – so the positive is still the basis; but the negative is significantly shorter than the positive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a language exists. It seems to be a language universal, that positive is default. It's for the same reason that a language may lack a word for "bad", but may not lack a word for "good".

Comment: Could you support your assertion about it being a language universal? And which languages lack a word for "bad"?

Comment: If the opposite doesn't exist anyway, then what would be the point of having word for "good"?

Comment: @ba Aztec does not have a word for "bad". They can say "amō cualli" though, lit. "not good". This is for example how one of the translations of the Lord's prayer was done; in that line "deliver us from evil", "evil" is rendered as amō cualli.

Comment: @lemontree of course is is useful to be able to describe something as good. Don't you think?

Comment: @ba I can't easily support that assertion (I'm in the middle of a house move; my books are packed away) this is why I phrased it so tentatively. But I think it's in "Atoms of Language" by Mark Baker.

Comment: The problem is that the universality claim requires an impossible infinite search to verify. It is an observationally uncontradicted generalization at least in my experience and awareness of the literature. But I don't know if it's contradicted in Nivkh or Mapuche.

Comment: @user6726 Exactly. That's why I said "it seems like ... ". It's impossible to say for sure because we can't observe every possible languoid

Comment: Though actually, loathe as I am to suggest appeal to authority, the claim is implied in the WALS chapter on negative morphemes.

Comment: @Wilson Or is amokali the Nahuatl word for bad? Etymologically it may be derived, but that doesn't mean it's not the true lexeme now. NSM advocates identify it as the expression of the BAD semantic prime. The test would be whether they can translate "not good but not bad", and I'm sure they could.

Comment: @curiousdannii quite possibly. But that looks a lot like "ungood" to me.

Comment: As far as I know, the Greenlandic word for _good_ is _ajunngilaq_, which means ‘not bad’, so Greenlandic is an example of a language that has a basic, underived words for ‘bad’ (_ajor_), but not for ‘good’ (negated form of ‘bad’).

Comment: Are you sure about that @Janus ? Off the top of my head there's "nuann".

Comment: @Wilson I don’t know what _nuann_ is, but it’s not Greenlandic; final geminates are not phonotactically possible in (West) Greenlandic. Oqaasileriffik gives _ajunngitsoq_ and _assuarnaateqanngitsoq_ (both negated), but also _pitsaasoq_ ‘very good’, which I didn’t know (and which is derived from _pitsak_ ‘excellent’). Can’t find a non-negated word that means just ‘good’, only stronger words (amazing, excellent, magnificent, fabulous, etc.). [_Ajunngilaq_ apparently means ‘that’s good’ or ‘he’s all right’, so slight misremembering on my part there.]

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I could have sworn I knew _nuann!_ as slang for _great!_, but I can't find any references now. Well anyway, since Greenlandic doesn't really have adjectives, there's also the noun _-tsialak_ which means "good", as in _atuarfitsialak_, "a good school".